# SQLite error (10) SQLite error (14) on Windows7 Dialog Box

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, directory

I'm trying to select a folder from the WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs package however I have noticed there's a significant delay in opening the dialog box for selecting the folders. I have also noticed these error codes:
SQLite error (10): delayed 1375ms for lock/sharing conflict
SQLite error (14): os_win.c:35288: (5) winOpen(C:\ProgramData\softthinks\DBRShell2.db) - Access is denied.

I am not running an SQl database in my program. It's just a simple winforms GUI application. How do I rectify these errors? My code for the dialog box is below:

```
CommonOpenFileDialog dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
    dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users";
    dialog.IsFolderPicker = true;
    dialog.Multiselect = false;
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
    {
       saveLocation = dialog.FileName;
    }
```

Comment: I realised that if I run Visual Studio as an admin, I don't have this issue. This is not ideal because I need the program to just run as is without having the user to right click on the program and run as an administrator.

Comment: smells like you have some fancy software intercepting things. 'softthinks'. Try uninstalling it

Comment: None of the common dialogs use SQL for any purpose, so it has nothing to do with the folder selection dialog. You have something else (either in your code or externally) that is causing this issue.

Comment: This issue seems to be replicated on other computers that I have tried the program on. So it must be something in my code but I don't have SQL running in my program at all so the errors it's throwing isn't making much sense to me.